# NLP Emotion Detection - Model fails to learn to recognize negations

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification, natural-language, tensorflow

I am working on a nlp emotion detection project. The emotions that I try to predict are 'joy', 'fear', 'anger', 'sadness'. I used some publicly available labeled datasets to train my model e.g. ISEAR, WASSA etc. I have tried the following approaches:

1. Traditional ML approached using bigrams and trigrams.
2. **CNN** with the following architecture:
   (X) Text -> Embedding (W2V pretrained on wikipedia articles) -> Deep Network (CNN 1D) -> Fully connected (Dense) -> Output Layer (Softmax) -> Emotion class (Y)
3. **LSTM** with the following architecture: (X) Text -> Embedding (W2V pretrained on wikipedia articles) -> Deep Network (LSTM/GRU) -> Fully connected (Dense) -> Output Layer (Softmax) -> Emotion class (Y)

The NN models achieve more than 80% accuracy but still when I use the the trained model to predict the emotion on text that includes some negation I get the wrong results. For example:

Text : "I am happy with easy jet, it is a great company!"

Predicts **Happy**

Text: I am not happy with easyjet #unhappy_customer

Predicts **Happy**

Any suggestions on how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negation is a tough problem in NLP. If you search on [Google Scholar for negation in sentiment analysis](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?as_ylo=2016&q=sentiment+analysis+negation&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5) there are dozens of papers that suggest some solutions.

The relatively simple things you can is:

- Detect such cases in your training data and upsample them.
- Generate synthetic training data by negating some of the training sentences that are simple enough for some rule-based editing after you do some NLP analysis over them (I would do it in [spaCy](https://spacy.io/)).